# Get updated value for a specific DataGridTemplateColumn in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Goal**

I am aiming to alter the selected value for a record and get the new value for a specific column in a DataGrid.

[image]

Right now, If I was to change a value in the Name column:

[image]

It detects the change:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Problem**

When I change the position title, it does not show the new value.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Question**

Why does it not detect the new value? And how do I do it?

**What I have tried**

- I have tried to add OnPropertyChanged to all properties (except the override) for both models. This didn't do anything.

**Code**

**Models**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public string PositionTitle { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is Position p && PositionId == p.PositionId;

    public override int GetHashCode() => PositionId.GetHashCode();
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> people;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set
        {
            people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Position> _positions;

    public ObservableCollection<Position> Positions
    {
        get { return _positions; }
        set
        {
            _positions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Name 1", Position = new Position { PositionId = 1, PositionTitle = "Position Title 1" } });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Name 2", Position = new Position { PositionId = 1, PositionTitle = "Position Title 1" } });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Name 3", Position = new Position { PositionId = 2, PositionTitle = "Position Title 2" } });

        Positions = new ObservableCollection<Position>();
        Positions.Add(new Position { PositionId = 1, PositionTitle = "Position Title 1" });
        Positions.Add(new Position { PositionId = 2, PositionTitle = "Position Title 2" });

        Command = new RelayCommand(param => EditData());
    }

    public ICommand Command { get; }

    private void EditData()
    {
        var newData = People;
    }


    #region Prop Changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**View**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Position Title">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Positions, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                                    DisplayMemberPath="PositionTitle"
                                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Position}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Save new data" Command="{Binding Command}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `SelectedValue` binding to `PropertyChanged`:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Position, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```